# Does Keras have functionality to copy input word vectors and backpropagate into only one set?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My goal is to create a RNN-CNN network in Keras that predicts categorical outputs based on paragraphs of text. In my current model the paragraphs are first embedded into feature vectors the fed into 2 cuDNNGRU layers, 4 Conv1D and MaxPooling layers, then to a Dense output layer.

However, I found a reference to a multi channel approach to dealing with word vectors that involved copying the initial vectors, running one set through a CNN layer then summing the output with the copy before pooling. This was done to prevent backpropogation into one set of vectors and therefore retain some semantic ideas from the original word vectors.

I've tried searching for this but the only thing associated with multi-channels and CNN is using multiple sizes of n-gram kernels. Does Keras offer any sort of functionality that could be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using function API.

Here is small example feel free to adapt to your need:

```
embed_input = Input(shape=(300,))
embedded_sequences = Embedding(10000, 10)(embed_input)
embed=SpatialDropout1D(0.5)(embedded_sequences)

gru=Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(200, return_sequences = True))(embed)

conv=Conv1D(filters=4,
            padding = "valid",
            kernel_size=4,
            kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
            activation='relu')(gru)

avg_pool = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(conv)
max_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv)
gru_pool = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(gru)


l_merge = concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool, gru_pool])



output = Dense(6, activation='sigmoid')(l_merge)
model = Model(embed_input, output)


model.summary()


output:

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)           (None, 300)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_9 (Embedding)         (None, 300, 10)      100000      input_10[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_9 (SpatialDro (None, 300, 10)      0           embedding_9[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_8 (Bidirectional) (None, 300, 400)     254400      spatial_dropout1d_9[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)               (None, 297, 4)       6404        bidirectional_8[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_6 (Glo (None, 4)            0           conv1d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_6 (GlobalM (None, 4)            0           conv1d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_7 (Glo (None, 400)          0           bidirectional_8[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 408)          0           global_average_pooling1d_6[0][0] 
                                                                 global_max_pooling1d_6[0][0]     
                                                                 global_average_pooling1d_7[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 6)            2454        concatenate_5[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 363,258
Trainable params: 363,258
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and structure of the graph:

[image]